# how to drop a single row based on a condition in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have the following data set which is a set of variables and their respective p values and R squared  values from a simple linear regression.

```
data have;
input Variable$ Probt R_value tie$;
cards;
    X1  0.0016  0.4344  .
    X2  0.0003  0.5204  .
    X3  0.0001  0.7497  yes
    X4  0.0001  0.9026  yes
run;
```

However, as you can see there are two variables that have the `Probt` value of 0.001 and I have created a variable called `tie` to capture a situation when two variables have the same p value.

What I want is the following. In situation where there is a tie, I want to break the tie by picking the variable with the highest R_value from the `tie` variable so that it looks like the following

```
data want;
    input Variable$ Probt R_value tie$;
cards;
    X1  0.0016  0.4344  .
    X2  0.0003  0.5204  .
    X4  0.0001  0.9026  yes
run;
```

Comment: SAS reports the number at 0.0001 but it rounds it and only shows as 0.0001, its likely underneath the values are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `probt` values are truly identical as they are in your example, you can do something as simple as using the `last.` variable (also assuming they're sorted in order, if not use `proc sort` first):

```
data want;
  set have;
  by descending probt  r_value;
  if last.probt;  *if it is the last record from any set of identical probt values, keep it;
run;
```

If the `probt` values are rounded and not truly identical, you need to make a variable first which is truly identical (using round).  If you already computed `tie` you may have done this already.

Answer (score 1):

something like below. but beware of compute tie value as mentioned by @reeza and @joe

```
data have;
input Variable$ Probt R_value tie$;
cards;
X1  0.0016  0.4344  .
X2  0.0003  0.5204  .
X3  0.0001  0.7497  yes
X4  0.0001  0.9026  yes
X5  0.0001  0.9028  yes
X6  0.0002  0.7499  yes
X7  0.0002  0.9027  yes
run;

proc sql;
create table want as 
select * from have a
where R_value not in 
(select min(R_value) from have b
where a.probt =b.probt
and tie ='yes');
```